# How to avoid redeploying the cloud function in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

The task is to write a cloud function that will get triggered whenever a json metadata is loaded in the gcs bucket as input. And this cf will write the json to the bq table. Now, The issue is although the keys of the json are present in the bq table as column names it gives an error that the column names don't exist in the bq table. This requires me to redeploy the cloud function every time. How do I avoid redeploying the CF?

Once I deploy the CF;each time a file is load in the bucket, it should automatically trigger the CF and it should write the json to bq table.